# In Gradle, is there a better way to get Environment Variables?

Tags: gradle, environment-variables, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In several Tasks, I reference jars in my home folder.

Is there a better way to get Environment Variables than

```
ENV = System.getenv()
HOME = ENV['HOME']

task copyToServer(dependsOn: 'jar', type: Copy) {

 from 'build/libs/'
 into HOME + "/something/plugins/"
}
```

This sets `$HOME` but I was hoping that I missed some magic from the documentation.

Comment: Be aware that before environment variable can be seen and used by Gradle, it needs to be exported, ex. `$ export FOO=bar`.

Comment: There's something I'm missing here... I have to put `def HOME`: Gradle 4.4.1 `Project` does not have a `HOME` property or an `ENV` property.  Could be something which dropped out ... ?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

Well; this works as well:

```
home = "$System.env.HOME"
```

It's not clear what you're aiming for.

Comment: or to your usage:   into "${System.env.HOME}/something/plugins"

Comment: Be aware that "$System.env.FOO" returns String with value "null", if the environment variable FOO is not defined as a system environment variable. It might be confusing since logging a String with value "null"  to console will print the same output as null variable.

Comment: or just home = System.env.HOME ?

Comment: If you are trying to get an environment variable that might not be set, it would be better to use `System.getenv('VAR')` which returns null if not assigned.  If you use `"$System.env.VAR"` then it will return the string `"null"`.

Comment: There's something I'm missing here... I have to put `def home`: Gradle 4.4.1 `Project` does not have a `home` property.  Could be something which dropped out ... ?

Comment: @chrish You can also use `System.env.VAR`. The reason `"$System.env.VAR"` returns (the string) `"null"` rather than `null` is because of string interpolation, not because of using `System.env` in place of `System.getenv`. Using `"${System.getenv('VAR')}"` has the exact same problem.

Answer (score 143):

I couldn't get the form suggested by @thoredge to work in Gradle 1.11, but this works for me:

```
home = System.getenv('HOME')
```

It helps to keep in mind that anything that works in pure Java will work in Gradle too.

Comment: Not sure why but I could only get the `System.getenv('HOME')` version to work for me. The other version kept returning `null`

Comment: Did you use single quotes instead of double by mistake, perhaps?

Comment: this is better than the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9856769/689223, because it returns `null` instead of `"null"` in case it does not exist.

Comment: As of new Gradle versions, it's better to use a provider, specially if you're doing it on the initialization or configuration phase:
`def homeProvider = providers.environmentVariable('HOST')`

Answer (score 22):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
val myVariable = System.getenv("MY_VARIABLE_NAME") ?: "my default value"
```

OR

```kotlin
val myVariable = System.getenv("MY_VARIABLE_NAME") ?: error("Env variable not found")
```

OR

```kotlin
val environment = System.getenv()
val myVariable = environment["MY_VARIABLE_NAME"] ?: "my default value"
// OR val myVariable = environment["MY_VARIABLE_NAME"] ?: error("Env variable not found")
```

Answer (score 13):

In android gradle 0.4.0 you can just do:

```
println System.env.HOME
```

**classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0**

Comment: thoredge said that 4 years before your answer!