# Access a path from .bashrc in gradle.build on a macbook pro

Tags: android, bash, gradle

I have a set a path in my .bashrc which I wanna have access to from my build.gradle file.
I'm using the commandLine method in gradle, but I can't seems to get it working.

My .bashrc:

```
APK_PATH="echo /Users/CPE/APK"
export APK_PATH
```

Which give me this result in a terminal:

```
$APK_PATH
/Users/CPE/APK
```

In my gradle.build file I have the following code:

```
def getOutputPath = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'echo', '$APK_PATH'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        def newName;
        def versionNumber = variant.versionName;
        def appName = variant.name.replace("Release","");
        def date = getDate();

        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            newName = appName + "_" + date + ".apk";
            releaseDir = getOutputPath() + "/" + appName;
        } else {
            newName = variant.name;
        }

        variant.outputFile = new File(releaseDir, newName);
    }
```

When i'm trying to make a release build I get the following error:

> Unable to open '$APK_PATH/ostran/ostran_20141209.apk' as zip archive

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854176/in-gradle-is-there-a-better-way-to-get-environment-variables) it looks like you should be getting `APK_PATH` like `System.getenv('APK_PATH')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the .bashrc file you can use your local [gradle.properties](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html) which I found WAAAY easier!

> You can place a gradle.properties file in the Gradle user home directory. The properties set in a gradle.properties file can be accessed via the project object. The properties file in the user's home directory has precedence over property files in the project directories.
>
> If this property does not exist, an exception will be thrown and the build will fail. If your build script relies on optional properties the user might set, perhaps in a gradle.properties file, you need to check for existence before you access them. You can do this by using the method hasProperty('*propertyName*') which returns true or false.

my flavors.gradle

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (project.hasProperty('APK_PATH')) {
            def appName = variant.name.replace("Release", "");
            def releaseDir = variant.outputFile.parent
            def newName = variant.name;

            if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
                newName = appName + "_" + getDate() + ".apk";
                releaseDir = APK_PATH + appName;
            }

            variant.outputFile = new File(releaseDir, newName);
        }
    }
```