# Passing envs into gradle build?

Tags: docker, gradle, gradlew

I am using gradlew within a container for a CI build.

ENV values are not being recognized when I add them in the bash shell.

Is there a way of passing the envs into the gradle build parameter or should the above be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about the problem here, is that you cannot read the variables inside gradle?

This question might help: [In Gradle, is there a better way to get Environment Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854176/in-gradle-is-there-a-better-way-to-get-environment-variables)

`version = System.getenv("JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "0.1-SNAPSHOT"`

is working fine in my `build.gradle` scripts.

Here there is an example:

Well, that should definitely work fine.

that's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

task('hello') {
  println System.getenv("HI")
}
```

So, if I run:

`export HI="hello there"`

`gradle hello`

I get this:

```
hello there
:hello UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.869 secs
```

This works. Just make sure that the ENV variables are correctly defined in your CI conf.

Comment: basically i'm trying to build a project within a container and the project contains envs that I used locally. I am using a gradle wrapper to replicate my local gradle environment but cannot replicate the envs within the container - for example ADMIN=password is unrecognised when I run the gradlew script within the container.