# How do you setup variables in build.gradle.kts

Tags: java, kotlin, build.gradle

In build.gradle I Know you can do this

```
ext {
    dbUsername = System.getenv("DB_USER").toString()
    dbPassword = System.getenv("DB_PASS").toString()
    libsUserNameNew = System.getenv("LIBS_USERNAME_NEW").toString()
    libsPassNew = System.getenv("LIBS_PASS_NEW").toString()
    gitShortTag = System.getenv("SHORT_SHA").toString()
    repoName = System.getenv("REPO_NAME").toString()
    group = "app.test.customerservicepoc"
    mainClass = "app.test.customerservicepoc.CustomerServicePOC"
}
```

How can I achieve the same using `build.gradle.kts`
This is what I have tried

```
var dbUsername =""
var dbPassword =""
var LibsUserNameNew = ""
var LibsPassNew = ""
var gitShortTag  = ""
var repoName = ""
```

and then

```
ext {
    dbUsername = System.getenv("DB_USER").toString()
    dbPassword = System.getenv("DB_PASS").toString()
    kyoskLibsUserNameNew = System.getenv("LIBS_USERNAME_NEW").toString()
    LibsPassNew = System.getenv("LIBS_PASS_NEW").toString()
    gitShortTag = System.getenv("SHORT_SHA").toString()
    repoName = System.getenv("REPO_NAME").toString()
    group = "app.test.mms"
}
```

during build I end up getting errors

> - What went wrong: 945 Cannot invoke "String.toString()" because the return value of
>   "org.gradle.internal.classpath.Instrumented.getenv(String, String)" is
>   null

I am migrating the project to `kotlin gradle`, how can I define the variables in kotlin gradle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Gradle, is there a better way to get Environment Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854176/in-gradle-is-there-a-better-way-to-get-environment-variables)

Comment: Hi @MartinMarconcini nope it doesn't, I know how to that, my question is how to migrate the build.gradle variables to build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is shown in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854176/in-gradle-is-there-a-better-way-to-get-environment-variables), `System.getenv` is a static java method that doesn't guarantee the nullability of the returned String. In Kotlin, this is a compilation error. So what the compiler is telling you is "I cannot guarantee that calling `toString()` on the returned string won't crash with a NullPointerException because the JVM method `getenv` doesn't guarantee it". I'd argue that you don't need the `toString()` call at all.

```
lateinit var db: String
// or
var db: String? = null //this can now be null


//then
ext {
    db = System.getenv("YOUR_DB") ?: "" //UPDATE: you also need this since getenv can return null, or you need to make the variable `String?`
//or
    db = System.getenv("YOUR_DB") ?: "" // since it can be null, set some fallback, like empty or null
}
```

This should work no problem.

#### UPDATE

I've created a new empty android project with compose (which uses build.gradle.kt instead of groovy), and added this:

```
lateinit var something1: String
var something2: String? = null

ext {
    something1 = System.getenv("something") ?: ""
    something2 = System.getenv("something2") ?: ""
}
```

[image: Image of Android Studio editor with a short code snippet]

It compiled no problem. (And I'd assume it would work if the environment variables were set).

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s`

#### Update 2 a real test

I've actually done this

```
lateinit var something1: String
var something2: String? = null

ext {
    something1 = System.getenv("SHELL") ?: ""
    something2 = System.getenv("SHELL") ?: ""
}

tasks.register("printSomething") {
    println("Something 1 is $something1")
    println("Something 2 is $something2")
}
```

Then I ran `./gradle printSomething`

And here's the result:

[image: Image of terminal emulator where gradlew printsomething was executed and the output is as expected according the code snipet above this image.]

Comment: Hi @MartinMarconcini the challenge I have is from `groovy` to `kotlin`, how do you do it

Comment: The above snippet works on both `groovy` *and* `kotlin`. Their syntax is moderately similar. I tested it on a fresh Android Studio project.