# using a common variable in settings.gradle.kts and build.gradle.kts

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using Gradle in my JAVA project, and I'm using the same URL in both `settings.gradle.kts` and `build.gradle.kts` files.

The URL is duplicated in both files and I want to declare it once and use it in both of the files in the way gradle designed to do that (no hacks).

I've tried the following:

1. Using the project extras but could find a way to use it in both files but only in the build file.
2. Declare the variable in the top of the `settings.gradle.kts` file and then try to access it from the build file - with no success.

I know I can use the `gradle.properties` file but it's local for each developer and I don't want everyone to add it to their file.

I'm trying to find the way that would be transparent to the team.

this is how it looks now:

`settings.gradle.kts`

```
pluginManagement {
    val nexusUsername: String by settings
    val nexusPassword: String by settings

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = nexusUsername
                password = nexusPassword
            }

            val nexusBaseUrl = System.getenv("NEXUS_BASE_URL") ?: "my-default-url"
            url = uri("$nexusBaseUrl/nexus/content/repositories/gradle-plugins/")
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat

plugins {
    java
    checkstyle
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}


subprojects {

    val nexusUsername: String by project
    val nexusPassword: String by project

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "NexusPublic"
            credentials {
                username = nexusUsername
                password = nexusPassword
            }
            val nexusBaseUrl = System.getenv("NEXUS_BASE_URL") ?: "my-default-url"
            url = uri("$nexusBaseUrl/nexus/content/groups/public/")
        }
    }
```

and I want `nexusBaseUrl` to be declared once and used in both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gradle.properties` shouldn't be local for each developer, it shouldn't be part of gitignore.

I recommend getting `nexusUsername` and `nexusPassword` from the environment variables instead, and having `nexusBaseUrl` on `gradle.properties`, the same way you have the username and password right now.

To get from environment variable, use `System.getenv("NEXUS_USERNAME")` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71052405/4363776).